# MediaRecorder "onstop" event is fired twice in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, web-mediarecorder

In my app, I'm using MediaRecorder to record a short video (up to 30s) from a user and then send it to the backend. To detect that recording has stopped, I use "onstop" event of MediaRecorder and in its callback I construct a video file and invoke uploading process. In Chrome and Edge it works fine. The event invokes only once, but in Safari I see different behavior, the *"onstop"* and *"ondataavailable"* events invoke twice. Therefore, my logic is broken, the backend receives two video files, the first one is broken usually, the second one is ok.

```
this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
  mimeType,
  videoBitsPerSecond,
});

this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', () => {
  console.debug('dataavailable');
});

this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
  console.debug('stop');
});

this.mediaRecorder.start();
console.debug('start');
```

Is this a bug of Safari or normal behavior?

Comment: How is this code called? Are you sure it's being called only once? I can't repro on Safari 15.4 (17613.1.17.1.13) https://jsfiddle.net/s0mrzqxh/ That you receive multiple `dataavailable` events is normal. Just the `stop` one should fire only once.

Comment: Yes, `mediaRecorder.start();` this fragment invokes only once. This code is inside  mobx store's method. But in logs I see that it triggers only once.

Comment: Currently, decided to use debounce for onstop callback. It may be a temporary solution.

Comment: Do you also experience the issue in the fiddle I provided in my previous comment? If not, try to add things little by little until it does.

Comment: I am seeing a similar thing - mediaRecorder's start() is called twice though stop() is only once.